# Design iOS View in Code without storyboard

Tags: ios, view, cgrect

I want to design and generate view elements in code, without using `storyboard`. But I haven't figure out a simple way to locate where should I put my view elements by describing its `CGRect`. For example, I can drag a `button` direct into the `storyboard` and put it where i want, however, in code, I have to write something like

```
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(24.0f, 113.0f, 271.0f, 140.0f)];
```

Is there any way or any software can help me?

Comment: Why you are looking for another software. Instead you can go for either creating story boards or consider using XIBs.

Comment: Any specific reason to create view elements through code?

Comment: it is a matter of style, same may do not like drag & drop style and prefer to code on their own and feel the full control

Comment: "Is there any way or any software can help me?" yes its called Storyboards....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit broad. You can create your view in code by including in your subclass of UIViewController properties for each subview (control) element and then make all the initialisation in designated initialiser and setting frames and other customisation in viewDidLoad method most likely. But for details where to what set you should go to references for UIViewController lifecycle as it may depend on what you want to achieve. in some cases setting frames in viewDidLoad will be fine whereas sometimes you will need to make some changes in viewDidLayoutSubviews for example.

Comment: I understand your meanings. I truelly can add all elements I want in ViewDidLoad, but meanwhile, I still don't know how to set the exact location or size for each elements. The reason I want to do everything in code is that I have already build the structure of the app.

Comment: doing in code you need to figure it out on your own, because I understand that you do not know the right values for frames am I right?

Comment: if you have a design you can measure the values (they probably will be in pixels) so keep in mind that the values you are placing into the setFrame method are in points, except measuring the design the other better method would be to go for xibs which you avoid, if you do not have a design then I guess you will try to figure out the values on your own